# Debian killing ffmpeg

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg

It must be some kind of Linux update because all of a sudden, after years of `ffmpeg` usage with Debian, `ffmpeg` gets killed without a logic reason. The funny part is there is no trace of killings in log files inside `/var/log`. Nothing!

The killings are more or less random, sometimes it happens after 1 second, other times after 50 seconds.

While transcoding `ffmpeg` outputs "`Killed`" and after few rows it outputs:

> Exiting normally, received signal 15.

The same behaviour happens with 4 different machines with Debian, kernel 3.16 and 4.9 with a lot of RAM, so memory is not the issue.

If have tried even with `nice` but no avail.

This problem is related to Debian only which kills all sort of CPU demanding processes, even GIT or wget.

When compiling h264 libraries I'm getting logged out from Debian. Things are getting worser. Still no log files.

Is there a kind of setting that limits CPU or some other devilry that is ruining my happiness? Is it possible that I'm the only person that has this problem with 4 different Debian systems?

Comment: Signal 15 is SIGTERM. Guess: You are using some incompatible libraries, and the CPU somehow ends up in the signal handler. Try to update all libraries involved, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: You are right. I tried the same command on Ubuntu and everything works as expected. So it's an OS related issue.

Comment: Don't know why it's doing that. Are you using the version from the repository (IIRC, it may be the old, dead, buggy, counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" from Libav)? You can try [downloading a static build of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and seeing if that works, and maybe it can help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I have compiled ffmpeg personally, plus I've tried the static build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/. I think it is not ffmpeg's fault it must be something with Debian, on Ubuntu it works fine. The fact is that I tried different Debian machines and versions, from 8.1 to 8.5 and the result is the same. So it must be a systematic Debian's problem.

Comment: Is there a cpu time limit? See output of `ulimit -a`. Are you on a VM or shared hosting? I believe Debian 8 uses systemd, so perhaps view logs via `journalctl`.

Comment: I had the same error with `ffmpeg`. Running `journalctl` showed that process ran out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's typical behavior for images larger than 4000p, if you got a NV GPU try [building ffmpeg it from source](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/)

Answer (score -2):

For error shown app recive the kiling signal . You can check log for which app or why app killed ffmpeg

For some app need run after killed we have reswpan setting . When app killed . It will be run again automatically

Comment: There is no log nowhere. This is the problem. Debian does not log any error, ffmpeg does not log any error. It's the craziest thing I have even seen.

Comment: You can get full dump of ffmpeq with -report switch

Comment: It's not an ffmpeg error so it does not log anything unusual, it's Linux kernel sending signal 15 to ffmpeg, for unknown reasons. Ffmpeg can only prepare for shutdown and then quits.